# Volume of a k parallelopiped

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds

When we study Manifolds we often encounter the formula for volume of a parallelopiped as

Vol=$\sqrt{det(X.X^{T})}$

My question is:
Why is the above determinant($det(X.X^{T})$) always non negative ?
Can someone provide an easy proof or intuition ?(It is obvious in the case where $X$ is square,can you prove the other cases)

Comment: X need not be a square matrix!

Comment: It is positive semi-definite self-adjoint. These matrices are diagonalizable with nonnegative eigenvalues. Hence $det$ of this is nonnegative.

Comment: Can you give a proof of why that is true?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

First, it suffices to note that if $X$ has linearly-independent rows, then $XX^T$ is [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix).  It follows that the eigenvalues of $XX^T$ are positive, so that $XX^T$ has positive determinant.

Another approach is to use the [Cauchy-Binet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) formula to find that
$$
\det(AA^T) = \sum_{S \subset \{1,\dots,n\}, |S| = m} \det(A_S)^2
$$
where $A_S$ denotes the $m \times m$ matrix whose columns are the $i$th column of $A$ for all $i \in S$.  Because the above is a sum of squares, it must be non-negative.  When $A$ has linearly independent rows, there exists an $S$ such that $\det A_S$ is non-zero, so that the above sum is in fact positive.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $X^TX$ is self-adjoint, hence it is diagonalizable. Also note that $(x,X^TXx)=(Xx,Xx)=||Xx||^2\geq 0$ for any vector $x$. Hence, all eigenvalues are nonnegative.

Hence we can write $X^TX=VDV^*$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries and $V$ is unitary. Hence $det(X^TX)=det(D)\geq 0$.

Comment: The question is about $XX^T$, however.

Comment: @amd same thing.. take $Y=X^T$

Comment: So edit your answer to match the question.